# Using Wii U on wireless network with username and password

Tags: wii-u, networking

I just moved into college, and the wireless network on campus requires a username and password. When I tried connecting my Wii U to the network, there was no field for username. Am I unable to connect to the network? I then noticed there's no ethernet port on the Wii U. Can I use a USB to Ethernet adapter?

Comment: I can only comment on the second part; yes you can use a usb Ethernet adapter. You should be able to use any adapter, but Nintendo does sell their own branded one.

Comment: Wireless access points don't need usernames.  If it asks for one, use a browser.  It should get you to a login screen.

Comment: @Frank: some wireless connection types *can* have usernames/passwords as part of the connection process, such as WPA-2 with PEAP, but they are very much in the minority. It's quite likely the Wii U won't support these methods, as they're pretty much limited to enterprises -- if that's what is used, user is probably out of luck. JShoe: when you connect on your PC/Laptop/whatever, does it ask you when you connect or when you open a browser?

Comment: @TZHX Huh.  I've never run into a wireless point that needs a username.  Most often, it's a gated browser site that limits access, most likely due to these other types not being supported that easily.

Comment: @Frank as I said, they're in the minority. But, for example, the eduroam network used for wireless access on many university campuses in Europe uses it.

Comment: @TZHX When I connect. Definitely not a browser thing.

Comment: @JShoe then I'm afraid you're probably out of luck. :(

Comment: @Frank When a network is using EAP authentication it can require a username token. My college did the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Does the WiiU Setup panel complain that it can't connect?  Or does it seem to consider itself connected yet programs will complain that they can't access other sites?  That is, the WiiU's Setup page shows a connection between WiiU and 'network device', but then fails between 'network device' and 'internet'?

If the former, I have no ideas.  But if the latter, then:

It may be that the wireless network actually lets anybody 'connect', *but* until you provide a school username-and-password it just responds to every single network request with a login-page.  If that's the case, try starting the WiiU's web browser, and see if you can get that login-page.   Once the network believes that your wireless-card belongs to an authenticated user, it will start honoring all further requests from it.

(This is a common approach to networks, and this sol'n has nothing to do w/ a Wii U per se, and might apply in any situation where you try to connect with anything besides a browser.)

...Apologies if you already knew/understood all this.

Answer (score 0):

If Not-Just-Yeti's suggestion doesn't work, you can try setting up the connection manually.

I'll assume you were using the automatic setup method on the Wii U. This is good for most users, but the network you'll be connecting to is not typical.

Take some of your cues from the [Nintendo support page on connecting your Wii U to the internet](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1643/p/431/c/187/session/L3RpbWUvMTQwODM5MjIyOC9zaWQvMjc3YXRhKmw%3D):

> From the Wii U Menu, select "System Settings."
>
> Using the Left Stick, select the "Internet" icon and press the A Button.
>
> Tap "Connect to the Internet."
>
> Tap "Connection Types" or press the Y Button.
>
> Select "Manual Connection."
>
> Tap "SSID" and enter your Wi-Fi network's name (case-sensitive).
>
> Tap "Security" and select your encryption method, then enter in your Wi-Fi network's security key.
>
> If you are using a proxy server, tap the arrow to the right, select "Proxy Settings," and enter in your proxy information (most networks do not require this configuration).
> When finished, tap "Save "or press the B Button.
>
> Tap "Save" again.
>
> Tap "Connection Test" to test your connection.
>
> Tap "OK" if the connection test was successful.
>
> If you receive an error, [click here](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1028) and enter your error code into our error code lookup tool.
>
> If you wish to set this network as your default network, tap "Set."

This is how you use the manual configuration settings for the Wii U. They're actually pretty powerful. If you're unsure what details you need to connect your system, give the help desk of your institution a call, and tell them you need help connecting a device to the network, and that you are needing to configure manual settings on the device. They should be able to provide you with the details of the network including security, proxy information, etc.

Best of luck!