# How to connect Wii U to username / password internet connection?

Tags: wii-u

I live in a college dorm, and with most modern colleges all students have user accounts. We use these accounts for many school-related things; including logging into the internet. From my windows 8 machine it's not a problem, the password entry menu just has two text boxes instead of one. But my newly purchased Wii U doesn't seem to be able to handle this type of internet login, and still only provides what seems like a single entry box for a WAP passphrase. Is it still possible to log into my college network from my Wii U, or am I out of luck?

I saw a [previous post related to my problem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/181390/82917), but no one there had a concrete answer.

Edit: I ended up just buying a wireless router and plugging it into the ethernet jack in my dorm room.

Answer (score 1):

Typically in these kinds of wireless setups are open wi-fi (no WEP/WAP needed) and after you connect you would open the web browser on the console and visit a web page of some kind to trigger the login prompt. Once you have completed your login you should be able to go back to whatever game you want to use online.

What is typically happening on the back-end is the system is authenticating your IP with your login credentials and assigning a IP lease to your user ID for the duration of that network session. Once you disconnect it drops the lease.

The other thing to be concerned about here is they may be firewalling all but a hand full of internet ports as well as having a login, so even if you log in, you can get to web pages (on port 80), but the ports the games use to connect to their server will not be allowed to have communications.

I would suggest you try the trick I listed first and report your results. If it doesn't work then you'll likely need to resort to the wired connection, or network sharing via a PC of some kind as one of the other answers suggested.

Comment: The problem isn't that the connection was limited, it's that it wouldn't connect to the network at all. I ended up buying a router connected to the ether net jack in my dorm room to solve the problem. It also lets my roommate and I use our wireless printer and play games on lan together.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to work out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is all theorically because I never been in US colleges or whatever, and I am not quite sure how you use the internet connection there, but this is what I can think of. The only way I'd see this work is having 2 WiFi cards (One that connects to your college network using the user/pass) once the connection is established, you share that connection with the 2nd Wifi adapter (which would then act as a "router" of some sort, like your smartphone, can you make it a router with an option, so you share your 4G connection). Then you have the WiiU connect to the 2nd Wifi adapter.

Again, this is all theorical and I cannot garantee it would work in anyway. So maybe someone has a better or working idea.

Comment: As well as this strange password ed connection, we also have access to a wired Connection. I'm considering buying a router to plug into it so that my roommate and I can use it as a local high speed private WiFi for the wii u and a printer we bought.

Comment: @user2373676 Be very careful with that. It is against most college policies to do so. Make the network hidden if you do.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, your console connects but won't go to the internet right?

Just accept. Then set the connection, open the browser, the user name and password page should automatically open.

I do it in hotels all the time